# How to add jvm custom propertis in bulk in Websphere

Tags: java, websphere

Our application is deployed in websphere and uses lots of custom jvm properties.
Right now we are adding the properties one by one through admin console.

This is a pain during development phase.
Because every day after syncing their code, each and every developer needs to find out if a new property has been added/renamed and do those changes in their own console. Else the application wont start.

It also takes a lot of application setup time, while deploying to various testing environments.

Could you help me identify the place where websphere stores these custom properties? We are thinking of writing a code to update that file (?) directly instead of adding one by one through admin console.

Please help.

P.S:- We are not allowed to use jython in our local :(

Comment: can you use jacl? (alternative scripting language to jython)

Comment: 1) add 1 property in the console
2) click the command assistance button to see the scripting command
3) profit

Comment: Thanks @aguibert for the idea. I didnt use jacl before but I will give a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the server.xml configuration for that given server, located somewhere like

`Dmgr/config/cells/cellName/nodes/nodeName/servers/server1/server.xml`

You can inspect the `<processDefinitions>` element and add a "systemProperties" stanza like:

`<systemProperties xmi:id="Property_1460665921900" name="someName" value="someValue" required="false"/>`

DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK. The "Property_1112223334445" part is fragile, and you need to make sure it has a unique 13-digit number at the end.

Or, you can modify the "genericJvmArguments" tag in the same file, using a format more like `-DsomeName=someValue`

Finally, if you do have jacl scripting access, there is an article on updating using scripting [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_jvm.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will spend some time on the jacl approach first. But this is exactly what I wanted.